# Cisco ASA single isakmp policy for multiple crypto map

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

We are going to setup multiple `site-to-site` tunnels to our remote office and every tunnel configuration is identical (same hash,encryption etc).

The question is: Do I need to create a separate `isakmp` policy for each tunnel or do I just define a single policy and it will share the policy with multiple `crypto map` (phase 2) configurations?

I have the following policy:

```
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 28800
```

Here is the crypto-map for `site0`

```
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map vpn_site0 1 match address ACL_VPN_SITE0
crypto map vpn_site0 1 set pfs
crypto map vpn_site0 1 set peer 35.35.35.1
crypto map vpn_site0 1 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA
crypto map vpn_site0 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map avpn_site0 interface outside
```

## Question:

1. Do I need to create an `isakmp` policy for `site1` if everything is same? How does `isakmp` policy map with `crypto map`?
2. Can I use the same transform `crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac` for all of the other sites?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you have multiple LANs on each side that you would like to connect using ipsec?
If yes, may I suggest to configure GRE tunnel between the sites, and add a routes to LAN networks of the other side via the tunnel.
Then you could to encrypt only the tunnel traffic using access list selector for GRE traffic, example: access-list 100 permit gre any any.
This way you using one crypto map, but encrypting several networks.

Comment: We are going to use IPsec tunnel, and yes every site has own LAN subnet. Just like star network topology.

Comment: Not tested, but I think, you will have to create different crypto map for each site, but you could use the same transform-set and isakmp policy for each crypto map. 
Also , I didn't see "mode tunnel" under your transform-set. This suppose to create ipsec tunnel of type ESP tunnel (allows encryption) and not AH tunnel.
Also reminder for my previous comment: reccomend to use GRE tunnel.
Just try and see what works for you, and tell us what configuration worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The answer is: No, you (do not need to) cannot create seperate (same/duplicate) isakmp policies for different tunnels which have the same isakmp policy setups. That means if you have only single and same `crypto ikev1 policy 10` on firewalls at your HeadQuater and Remote Offices, that is enough.

   - And if you try to create an another identical isakmp policy (let us
     say policy 20), ASA firewall will not accept it and throw out the
     message `ikev1 policy 20 is superceded by identical policy 10`.
   - When we have more than one isakmp policy on ASA firewalls, the
     firewall who initiates the ISAKMP negotiation will send all of its
     policies to the other end to find a match. The remote end starts
     checking all of the peer's policies against each of its configured
     policies in priority order (highest priority first - lowest policy
     number).
2. For your second question: yes, one and same ikev1 transform-set (IPSec policy) across your VPN tunnel configurations should not be a problem.
3. I found a problem with your `crypto map` configuration. `crypto map vpn_site0` and `crypto map avpn_site0` are not match

   You can apply ONLY ONE crypto-map per interface, here is outside interface. If you have multiple S2S VPN tunnels, you have to use the same crypto-map with different priority numbers. Therefore, you should name your crypto-map meaningful and use this for all of your tunnels terminated on that outside interface.

I would propose the crypto-map name is `crypto map vpn_sites` with below configuration:

```
crypto map vpn_sites 1 match address ACL_VPN_SITE0
...
crypto map vpn_sites 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map vpn_sites 2 match address ACL_VPN_SITE1
...
crypto map vpn_sites 2 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map vpn_sites 3 match address ACL_VPN_SITE2
...
crypto map vpn_sites 3 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
...
crypto map vpn_sites interface outside
```